# Next JS, Next Auth, and custom Okta Widget issue

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, next.js, okta, next-auth

I'm trying to use a custom okta widget to do the sign-in process for my next js app. I have an Okta provider set up under /api/auth. When I use the widget to log in, I have the redirectUri point to the okta provider at http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/okta to pass along the rest of the information and create a session. Kinda replicates what the normally hosted okta login widget would do.

My issue is I'm getting this error during the callback and I can't figure out why.  Any ideas?

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/MilesWinston23/nextjs-auth).

```
[next-auth][error][CALLBACK_OAUTH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#callback_oauth_error Invalid Compact JWE JWEInvalid: Invalid Compact JWE
    at compactDecrypt (C:\Users\miles\OneDrive\Documents\NextJs\nextjs-auth\node_modules\jose\dist\node\cjs\jwe\compact\decrypt.js:16:15)
    at jwtDecrypt (C:\Users\miles\OneDrive\Documents\NextJs\nextjs-auth\node_modules\jose\dist\node\cjs\jwt\decrypt.js:8:61)
    at Object.decode (C:\Users\miles\OneDrive\Documents\NextJs\nextjs-auth\node_modules\next-auth\jwt\index.js:64:34)
    at async useState (C:\Users\miles\OneDrive\Documents\NextJs\nextjs-auth\node_modules\next-auth\core\lib\oauth\state-handler.js:62:17)
    at async oAuthCallback (C:\Users\miles\OneDrive\Documents\NextJs\nextjs-auth\node_modules\next-auth\core\lib\oauth\callback.js:82:19)
    at async Object.callback (C:\Users\miles\OneDrive\Documents\NextJs\nextjs-auth\node_modules\next-auth\core\routes\callback.js:50:11)
    at async NextAuthHandler (C:\Users\miles\OneDrive\Documents\NextJs\nextjs-auth\node_modules\next-auth\core\index.js:186:28)
    at async NextAuthNextHandler (C:\Users\miles\OneDrive\Documents\NextJs\nextjs-auth\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:23:19)
    at async auth (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts:12:12)
    at async Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\miles\OneDrive\Documents\NextJs\nextjs-auth\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:184:9) {
  name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
  code: 'ERR_JWE_INVALID'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okta does not send JWT encrypted. So it seems like your app expects it to be encrypted (JWE), so it fails